# PowerShell построчная обработка текста

Tags: powershell, текст

В списке указаны отделы и сотрудник:

```
Отдел снабжения:
Иванов
Петров
Отдел поставок:
Сидоров
Николаев
```

Надо привести к виду:

```
Отдел снабжения: Иванов
Отдел снабжения: Петров
Отдел поставок: Сидоров
Отдел поставок: Николаев
```

Алгоритм вижу следующий.
Если в строке встречается "Отдел" присвоить её переменной.
Иначе вставить значение переменной в начало строки.
Переход к следующей строке.

Подскажите, как это записать в виде кода?

Answer (score 0):

```
@" 
Отдел снабжения:
Иванов
Петров
Отдел поставок:
Сидоров
Николаев
"@ | Out-File d:\tmp\input.txt

Get-Content d:\tmp\input.txt | % {
    if ($_.Contains(":")){
        $prefix = $_
    }
    else{
        "$prefix $_"
    }
}
```